# How to make a socket between android and google app engine?

Tags: android, sockets, google-app-engine

I'm looking for a good way to make an update service between google app engine and my android device.

Google app engine is limiting me in the number of calls.

so making a broadcast every few minutes is not good.

I'd like to use something like a socket listener that will listen to incoming updates (JSON format)
and in the server side the update function.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)?

Comment: I think its quite complecated isnt?
I mean in GCM it sends out notifications, I don't need notifications like that.
I'm developing an app that add new DB for example and i need to add it to the other client to see (just like a chat app)

Comment: What do you mean by notification? The UI related to the notification bar? it is optional... GCM works fine without showing notifications

Comment: when using GCM i need to implement it in the google app engine server as well?

Comment: Yes, but there should be an example/server side lib (also from google)...

Comment: ok thanks ill give it a shot:)